# http://dev.twitter.com/ redirects to http://twitter.com/

Tags: api, redirect, twitter

I am trying to access my Twitter API but the call is failing due to the redirect. Does anybody know why this is happening and or how I can fix it? Yes, I am signed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the "Use HTTPS" on Chrome, or a similar extension?

For me, it redirects http://dev.twitter.com to https://dev.twitter.com, which in turn redirects to https://twitter.com

Ideally, the extension would offer more control in how it matches domains. Meanwhile, a quick workaround is to open an incognito window, for which extensions are disabled, and view dev.twitter.com there.